# pandas dataframe creating columns with loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add new columns and fill them with data with for loops, take data from Price column and insert 1000 iterations into new dataframe column, after 1000 Price column iterations then make a new column for 1000 more, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_frame = pd.read_csv('candle_data.csv', names=['Time', 'Symbol','Side', 'Size', 'Price','1','2','3','4','5'])
price_df = pd.DataFrame()
count_tick = 0
count_candle = 0
for price in data_frame['Price']:
    if count_tick < 1000:
        price_df[count_candle] = price
        count_tick +=1
    elif count_tick == 1000:
        count_tick = 0
        count_candle +=1


price_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary that you loop through the data frame , you can use slicing to achieve this, look at below sample code. I have loaded a Dataframe with 100 rows and trying to create column -'col3' from first 50 rows of 'col1' and post that column 'col4' from the next 50 rows of 'col1'. You could  modify the below code to point to your columns and the values that you want

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        col1 = np.linspace(0,100,100)
        col2 = np.linspace(100, 200, 100)
        dict = {'col1':col1,'col2':col2}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
        df['col3']= df['col1'][0:50]
        df['col4'] = df['col1'][50:100]
        print(df)
```

Solution 2 based on added info from comments

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    ### partition size for example I have taken a low volums 20
    part_size = 20
    ## number generation for data frame
    col1 = np.linspace(0,100,100)
    col2 = np.linspace(100, 200, 100)

    ## create initial data frame
    dict = {'col1':col1,'col2':col2}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    len = df.shape[0]
    ## tells you how many new columns you need
    rec = int(len/part_size)
    _ = {}
    ## initialize slicing variables
    low =0
    high=part_size
    print(len)
    for i in range(rec):
        if high >= len:
            _['col_name_here{0}'.format(i)] = df[low:]['col1']
            break
        else:
            _['col_name_here{0}'.format(i)] = df[low:high]['col1']
            low = high
            high+= part_size
    df = df.assign(**_)
    print(df)
```

Comment: thing is, the dataframe is huge, over 500k rows, and i need a easier way without having to create manually

Comment: @CosminGeorge - I have updated my answer with another script 2 which creates these columns dynamically and appends them to your data frame. You can set your partition size from this variable - 'part_size = 20' . you might have to do some tweaks in case your total rows are not divisible by part size , e.g ->rec = int(len/part_size) this would need to be changed to use ceil() function.